# Azure SQL Data Warehouse Polybase Query to Azure Data Lake Gen 2 returns zero rows

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, polybase, azure-data-lake-gen2

***Why does an Azure SQL Data Warehouse Polybase Query to Azure Data Lake Gen 2 return many rows for a single file source, but zero rows for the parent folder source?***

I created:

- Master Key (CREATE MASTER KEY;)
- Credential (CREATE DATABASE SCOPED
  CREDENTIAL) - uses the ADLS Gen 2 account key
- External data source (CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE)
- File format (CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT)
- External table (CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE)

Everything works fine when my external table points to a specific file, i.e.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ext].[Time]
(
    [TimeID] int NOT NULL,
    [HourNumber] tinyint NOT NULL,
    [MinuteNumber] tinyint NOT NULL,
    [SecondNumber] tinyint NOT NULL,
    [TimeInSecond] int NOT NULL,
    [HourlyBucket] varchar(15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION = '/Time/time001.txt',
    DATA_SOURCE = ADLSDataSource,
    FILE_FORMAT = uncompressedcsv,
    REJECT_TYPE = value,
    REJECT_VALUE = 2147483647
);
```

```
SELECT * FROM [ext].[Time];
```

***Many rows returned, therefore I am confident all items mentioned above are configured correctly.***

The Time folder in Azure Data Lake Gen 2 contains many files, not just time001.txt. When I change my external table to point at a folder, and not an individual file, the query returns zero rows, i.e.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [ext].[Time]
(
    [TimeID] int NOT NULL,
    [HourNumber] tinyint NOT NULL,
    [MinuteNumber] tinyint NOT NULL,
    [SecondNumber] tinyint NOT NULL,
    [TimeInSecond] int NOT NULL,
    [HourlyBucket] varchar(15) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION = '/Time/',
    DATA_SOURCE = ADLSDataSource,
    FILE_FORMAT = uncompressedcsv,
    REJECT_TYPE = value,
    REJECT_VALUE = 2147483647
);
```

```
SELECT * FROM [ext].[Time];
```

***Zero rows returned***

I tried:

- LOCATION = '/Time/',
- LOCATION = '/Time',
- LOCATION = 'Time/',
- LOCATION = 'Time',

But always zero rows. I also followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-load-from-azure-data-lake-store

***I tested all the files within the folder and individually each returns many rows of data.***

***I queried all the files from Blob storage and not ADLS Gen2 and the "Folder" query returns all rows as expected.***

***How do I query all files in a folder "as one" from Azure Data Lake Gen2 storage using Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Polybase?***

Comment: What do you put in the credential? Storage account key? SAS token? Service principal?

Comment: What are the actual folder and file names? I assume none of the files or parent folders start with “_” or “.”?

Comment: The credential uses the account key. Pointing at a specific file returns data, so I believe the credentials are good. The folder is "Time" and file "time001.txt", no special characters or folders or files starting "_" or ".".

Comment: I know it doesn't match the documentation, but have you tried adding a wildcard to the LOCATION: '/Time/*.txt'?

Comment: Thanks, @JoelCochran, but using wildcards didn't fix it.

Comment: It was a long shot, but I don't see anything else off the bat. My only other thought is that perhaps one of the files is malformed? According to the doc link you posted: "each row of the data being ingested must satisfy the table schema definition. If a row does not match the schema definition, the row is rejected from the load." Since you are specifying REJECT_VALUE = 0, wouldn't a single errant row would cause zero rows to return?

Comment: Great idea @JoelCochran. I tried your suggestion with REJECT_VALUE = 2147483647, but still, zero rows when querying the folder. I also experimented with REJECT_TYPE = percentage and got zero rows. I also performed some more tests:

- I have queried each file individually (LOCATION = '/Time/time001.txt', LOCATION = '/Time/time002.txt', etc.), and individually every single file within the folder returns many rows with zero errors.
- The same set of files within blob storage (not ADLS Gen2) does return many rows when querying the folder.

Comment: Have you double checked permissions?  I mean just to rule it out...

Comment: @wBob might be on to something. Since it is ADLS, could it be possible that the CREDENTIALS have access to the files in the folder, but not the folder itself? While I would assume an error message rather than 0 rows, it's worth ruling out.

Comment: Thanks, both. I am using the account key to authenticate. I just experimented with the access level on the ADLS Gen 2 container, trying all three options, including "anonymous read access for containers and blobs). All tests return zero rows.

Comment: Time to try COPY INTO.  It’s still in preview but is a similar approach to achieve the same outcome.  It might also help with your debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exactly same issue: the problem was on the Data Source protocol.

Script with error:

```
   CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE datasourcename
   WITH (
       TYPE = HADOOP,
       LOCATION = 'abfss://container@storage.blob.core.windows.net',
       CREDENTIAL = credential_name
```

Script that solves issue:

```
   CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE datasourcename
   WITH (
       TYPE = HADOOP,
       LOCATION = 'abfss://container@storage.dfs.core.windows.net',
       CREDENTIAL = credential_name
```

The only change needed was the LOCATION.

Thanks to the Microsoft Support Team for helping me on this.